# how to use returned list in ajax call from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am using ajax call to store the data in to DB and controller is returning the list of commentObject.
how can i access this list in JSP?
my ajax call is:

```
function StoreCommentAndRefreshCommentList(e) {
    var commentData = document.getElementById(ActualCommentTextId).value;
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'CommentStoreAndRetrieve',
        data : "commentData=" + commentData + "&ImageId=" + commetTextButtonId[1],
        success : function(commentList) {
            //alert('comments stored successfully');
            //alert('comment data is...'+res.CommentDataDoc[0]);

        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    }); 
}
```

please let me know how can i access list data here.

Comment: what data are you returning from ajax?base on that you can manipulate the response from ajax

Comment: you need to specify the `dataType: "json",` for json `dataType: "text",` for text etc.

Comment: You can't use data returned from Ajax in JSP. JSP runs server side. The output of the JSP gets delivered to the client. Ajax makes an HTTP request and returns the data to the client. By the time the data is on the client it is too late for JSP to do anything with it.

Comment: @Quentin It's not strictly true. Of course, it's important to distinguish client/server side, but you can assign data received on the client side to already existed JS variables (declared in JSP) or HTML elements. I don't know what SriniReddy want to do with such data, but I guess he may want to use it to update UI or store it to for some further actions (maybe he wants to avoid fetching it again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
i did used $.each(res, function (key, val) to iterate one by and built the tags dynamically using val field. here key holds the index position and val holds the corresponding object. then i did accessed one by one field by val.filedname(which we did create for pojo).

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
function StoreCommentAndRefreshCommentList(e) {
var commentData = document.getElementById(ActualCommentTextId).value;
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'CommentStoreAndRetrieve',
    data : "commentData=" + commentData + "&ImageId=" + commetTextButtonId[1],
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function(commentList) {
        alert($(commentList).text());

    },
    error : function(e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can f.e. create `<input type='hidden' id='someId'/>` in your JSP and then in your success function you can assign data like `$("#someId").val(...);`

Another idea would be create JS variable inside JSP by putting `<script>var myVar = ""</script>`. Then in your succes function you can refer to such 'global' variable. Althogh, I believe that usual assignment (`myVar = response.yourList`) wouldn't work for a `response` object (which is the case in your problem). The solution would be to  create an array `var arr = []` and then in for loop you can push some done into it.